# A basic problem with Solve

Tags: equation-solving

I have this equation:

```
4b*Cos[2t]-4a*Sin[2t]==4Cos[2t]+8Sin[2t]
```

Which I would like to solve. Without using mathematica, you can pretty easily see that a = -2 and b = 1, but when I solve it with mathematica it gives me various long results including sometimes tan, sec cot etc.

I can break it up into to parts like this:

```
Solve[4b*Cos[2t]==4Cos[2t],b]
Solve[-4a*Sin[2t]==+8Sin[2t],a]
```

However, the point with mathematica isn't to make everything manually, and I would hope there is a method to use, without manually editing the equations.

So my question is:
How do I solve this for a and b, with the results of a = -2 and b = 1?

Comment: You can try to use SolveAlways function.

Comment: So in the first example you have 1 Equation with 2 variables, in the second example you have 2 equations with 2 variables.

Don't you mean `Solve[{[4b*Cos[2t]==4Cos[2t],-4a*Sin[2t]==+8Sin[2t]},{a,b}]`?

Comment: I'm guessing that it has to be solved for any t, so the (proper) approach is to write `SolveAlways[
 4 b*Cos[2 t] - 4 a*Sin[2 t] == 4 Cos[2 t] + 8 Sin[2 t], t]` or rather `SolveAlways[4 b*Cos[2 t] - 4 a*Sin[2 t] == 4 Cos[2 t] + 8 Sin[2 t], {Sin[2 t], Cos[2 t]}]`

Comment: @mmal Thank you it works. Should I delete this question?

Comment: No, don't delete it (but you may try to improve it to make it clearer) . Let @mmal post his answer. We don't see enough `SolveAlways[]` uses around.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the `SolveAlways` function, which will solve your equation for all values of the parameters (in this case for any t). So the solution to your question is

```
SolveAlways[4 b*Cos[2 t] - 4 a*Sin[2 t] == 4 Cos[2 t] + 8 Sin[2 t], t]
```

or rather

```
SolveAlways[4 b*Cos[2 t] - 4 a*Sin[2 t] == 4 Cos[2 t] + 8 Sin[2 t], {Sin[2 t], Cos[2 t]}]

(* => {{a -> -2, b -> 1}} *)
```

since we know that $\sin$ and $\cos$ are orthogonal functions.